# Issue with a while loop in Python

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm a beginner when it comes to coding in general, I would love some help to understand why the last statement won't show on the terminal:

```
import random

def guess(x):
 random1= random.randint(1,x)
 user_number= input(f"guess the random number between 1 and {x}: ")
 while user_number != random1:
   if int(random1) < int(user_number):
       print("the number you chose is a little bit higher")
       user_number= input("try again :  ")
   elif int(random1) > int(user_number):
       print("the number you chose is a little bit lower")
       user_number= input("try again :  ")

 print("the number you chose is correct you're so lucky")

guess(9)
```

Everything works except for the last print. Can someone please help.

Comment: You haven't handled the case when `int(random1) == int(user_number)`, so when the guess is correct you'll be stuck in an infinite loop. Use an `else:` block, then print your messsage, then `break` out of the loop.

Comment: @qrsngky that's handled in the `while` condition, no?

Comment: @DominikStańczak I may have misread the code at first, but then found that in the end, the code still needs to have that type of checking, because e.g. `5=='5'`  is False in Python.

Comment: Which is why you should always sanitize your inputs!

Comment: Basically, the `while` condition failed to handle it because a string cannot "==" an integer in Python. Another possible way to go is by changing it to `while int(user_number) != random1:`

Answer (score 0):

If, for example, `random1 = 3` (and it's always helpful to debug with constant data instead of randomness!), then your `while` condition evaluates to `3 != "3"`, which is `True` because the integer 3 is not equal to the string "3", and your `while` loop gets stuck there.

Basically you should be more consistent and instead of having the `int` calls in the `if/elif` checks, wrap your `input` calls in those. That way, you're always working with a consistent type (integer for something that's meant to be an integer) and don't need to remember to apply any transformations to it elsewhere (like here, before the comparison).

Comment: I appreciate the advice and the explanation thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def guess(x):
    random1= random.randint(1,x)
    user_number= input(f"guess the random number between 1 and {x}: ")
    while int(user_number) != int(random1):
        if int(random1) < int(user_number):
            print("the number you chose is a little bit higher",random1)
            user_number= input("try again :  ")
        elif int(random1) > int(user_number):
            print("the number you chose is a little bit lower",random1)
            user_number= input("try again :  ")
    print(user_number == random1, user_number, random1) # number equal check
    print("the number you chose is correct you re so lucky")

guess(9)
```

I am here attaching the whole correct working code, as someone mentioned in the earlier answers, the input what you read from the user always been in the string format, so better you do typecasting when using it in the conditional and iteration loops, otherwise wrap the input field with integer datatype like,

`user_number= int(input(f"guess the random number between 1 and {x}: "))`

happy coding ..!

Answer (score 0):

When you take user input then its type is a string and you have to convert the user input from a string to an integer.

```
user_number= input(f"guess the random number between 1 and {x}: ")
```

instead of the above line try with the below line

```
user_number= int(input(f"guess the random number between 1 and {x}: "))
```

and also change the below lines and take input as an integer.

```
user_number = int(input("try again :  "))
```